# Creating multiple buttons using for loop in tkinter but having keyError

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter

I'm implementing multiple buttons using `for loop` in tkinter.

```
b = {}
        
all_Functions = {
    'Mass':self.standard_converter,
    'Length': self.scientific_converter,
    'Temperature': self.currency_converter,
    'Time': self.binary_to_decimal,
    'Luminous Intensity': self.binary_to_decimal,
    'Amount of Substance': self.binary_to_decimal,
    'Binary to Decimal': self.binary_to_decimal,
}

func = list(all_Functions.values())      
# buttons and functions........................
for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 6):
        b[i][j] = tk.Button(button_frames, border = 0, command = func[i])
        b[i][j].grid(row = i+1, column = j+1)
```

this is my code, anyone please help me solving the error. Error is showing in second last line which is `keyError: 0`

Comment: What is `b[i]` supposed to refer to?  You never add anything to `b` itself, only to the nonexistent second level of nesting.  Perhaps you want to use `b[i, j]` (tuples as keys, in a one-level data structure) - but I have no idea why you might want six indistinguishable copies of each Button, so I suspect I misunderstand your goals.

Comment: A `KeyError` indicates that you're trying to access a dictionary key that doesn't extist. `b` in this case is an empty dictionary, so there's nothing to access. I imagine this could be fixed by removing the declaration `b = {}` and replacing `b[i][j]` with a placeholder name like `btn`. That way you can still do `btn.grid()` in your loop

Comment: Every button which is creating by for loop is storing in the dictionary b. Simply I want multiple(2 or 3) buttons in a row and every button can call different function on click which are stored in ```all_functions``` dict. @jasonharper